# listbox selected item returning Null value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a listbox which is binded to a Viewmodel, i am using mouse_doubeclickevent to retrieve the selected item value but its returning null, what i could be missing here ? SWdistinct is a list

ViewModel:

```
public List<swversion> SWdistinct
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="CRSWUNIQUE" ItemsSource="{Binding SWdistinct}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SWdistinct,Mode=TwoWay}"  MouseDoubleClick="CRSWUNIQUE_MouseDoubleClick"   DisplayMemberPath="SW_Version" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"   />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void CRSWUNIQUE_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = CRSWUNIQUE.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
       // if (CRSWUNIQUE.SelectedItem != null)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show(item.Content.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` both be to `SWdistinct`? Are you sure that `SelectedItem` is actually null in your double click handler? It may be the cast to `ListBoxItem` that is returning null. What does SelectedItem have in it when examined in debug?

Comment: @TylerLee SWdistinct is a list , when i debugged this line and pointed the cursor on CRSWUNIQUE it showed like this `System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.count:2` and when i pointed to SelectedItem it showed me the value `SW_Version:myvalue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectedItem will give the object you bound. In this case it would be the object of swversion. Try below code.

```
private void CRSWUNIQUE_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var swversionitem = CRSWUNIQUE.SelectedItem as swversion;
    if (swversionitem != null)
       // if (CRSWUNIQUE.SelectedItem != null)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show(swversionitem.SW_Version.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfect. i had to only put var before swversionitem. Is there a way to trigger Mousedoubleclick in viewmodel and pass the selectedvalue to viewmodel ?

Comment: Yes you can trigger double click on viewmodel. Post that as a separate question. I will answer that.

Comment: Thank you, but its not allowing me to post the question, i should wait for 90 minutes :)

Comment: @SamKing I have  created a sample for passing selecteditem to viewmodel on doubleclick. I will post as separate answer on this post

Comment: @SamKing Check below answer or passing selecteditem to viewmodel on doubleclick

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i will add this to my code and test.

Answer (score 0):

Sample for passing selecteditem to viewmodel on doubleclick. Try below code.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Swversions}" x:Name="lstListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SW_Version}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                      Command="{Binding ElementName=lstListBox,Path=DataContext.ListDoubleClickCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public List<swversion> Swversions { get; set; }

    public ICommand ListDoubleClickCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Swversions = new List<swversion>()
        {
            new swversion() {SW_Version = "Version1"},
            new swversion() {SW_Version = "Version2"},
            new swversion() {SW_Version = "Version3"},
            new swversion() {SW_Version = "Version4"},
            new swversion() {SW_Version = "Version5"}
        };
        ListDoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDoubleClick);
    }

    private void OnDoubleClick(object parameter)
    {

    }
}

class swversion
{
    public string SW_Version { get; set; }
}
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```